# Python Multiprocessing Slower than Sequential Programming

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I looked up for a lot of questions concerning slowness in python multiprocessing, but none of them were able to solve my problem.

Inside my algorithm, I have a for instance from 0 to 2, that runs the most important function of the algorithm (and the most time-consumption one). The 3 iterations of the for instance are independent from each other. So, to take advantage of this feature, I was trying to run my algorithm using parallel processing.

The thing is that when I run my algorithm will parallel processing, the simulation time is higher than the sequential programming. Depending on the input data, my original sequential algorithm can take from ~30ms to ~1500ms to run. Even when I run the ~1500ms cases, the multiprocessing is slower. Is it because the multiprocessing have to deal with really computionally expensive problems to make it worth, or is there something I can do to make it work better for me?

For now I won't post my algorithm because it's really long, but just as an example, what I'm doing is this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def FUNCTION(A,B,C,f):
    R1 = A * B * C * f
    R2 = A * B / C * f # The function has several operations, i'm just doing an example here.
    return R, S

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool()

    while CP[0] or CP[1] or CP[2] or CPVT[0] or CPVT[1] or CPVT[2]:        

        f=0
           result1 = pool.apply_async(FUNCTION, [A0,B0,C0])  

    f=1
           result2 = pool.apply_async(FUNCTION, [A1,B1,C1]) 

        f=2
           result3 = pool.apply_async(FUNCTION, [A2,B2,C2]) 

        [R0,S0] = result1.get(timeout=1)
        [R1,S1] = result2.get(timeout=1)
        [R2,S2] = result3.get(timeout=1)
```

Any ideas why is it taking longer then the sequential way to do it, or any solutions to that issue?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do any of the operations involve file reading from disk?

Comment: The functions are called again and again while  `while` is `True`. Perhaps you're calling the functions more than necessary.

Comment: How many processors are you using?

Comment: No reading from disk inside the functions. The functions have to be called every while loop. This was done for the sequential non-parallel algorithm and the simulation time was faster. I'm using 3 processors, one for each function.